# Counterexample of $L^p(E)$ space when $m(E) = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Here is the proposition

> When $m(E)<\infty$, if $1 \leq p_2 < p_1 < \infty$, then
> $$
> L^{\infty}(E) \subset L^{p_1}(E) \subset L^{p_2}(E)
> $$

Is the condition $m(E) < \infty$ necessary? If yes, are there any counterexamples when $m(E) = \infty$?

Comment: yes of course... For example $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is $L^2(1,\infty )$ but not $L^1(1,\infty )$.

Comment: @Surb Ohhhh, yes.. Thank you Sir XD.

Comment: In fact, if $1 \le p < q < \infty$ then $L^q \not \subset L^p$ if and only if there exists a sequence $(A_n)$ of subsets of $E$ of arbitrary large measure, that is, $\mu(A_n) \to \infty$.